# Clearing MainGrid childs in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to remove "`r`", WPF user control, from my MainGrid.
This code is for adding user control, the `r`, to  Main Grid

```
   int a = 0;
   void patient_today() {

     foreach(var item in dbl.patientsToDay()) {

       if (a < 5) {
         // Add r per user reminder to main grid(User Control) & set design
         ReminderUR r = new ReminderUR();
         r.Text_ptName.Text = item.Patient.name;
         r.Text_Date.Text = item.Times + "  " + item.Dates;
         Grid.SetColumn(r, 0);
         Grid.SetRow(r, 1 + a); // add to next row
         Grid.SetColumnSpan(r, 3);
         MainGrid.Children.Add(r);
         a += 1;
       }

     }
   }
```

I tried use

```
MainGrid.childeren.remove(r)
```

but that did not work

**To short, I want to refresh the information in my grid**

Comment: Why isn't this an itemscontrol?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All code worked correctly**, the problem was at counting a.